# Compiling python project

Tags: python, compiler-errors

this is my first time on posting a thread on stackoverflow, but I have used this many times in the past. I am having a problem when compiling my python files. I have looked many times on here and on other sites on how to do this and I keep getting the same answers. For some reason, on my computer, I cannot run/install pip. Whenever I try to install pip by using the python command, it is not recognized. I saw a thread on here about using 'py' instead of 'python', this is accepted as a command but when I try to install pip it just errors. I have installed python several times and have also repaired it several times, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Welcome on SO. Can you be more specific about the problem you have? What do you do (exact commands), what do you expect and what do you get (error messages, program output etc) instead?

Comment: I am currently trying to compile a python file so I can send it to others without them needing to install python and also so my src code isn't leaked. The commands I have tried are 'python get-pip.py' and 'py get-pip.py'. The error message I get are, (python command) ''python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.' and for the py command, I get '(null): can't open file 'get-pip.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'

Comment: Why are you trying those commands?

Comment: @JakeStrouse Check that Python is added to your $PATH variable. If you're using a UNIX system, the command `which python` should return a file path to the directory that contains your Python executable. On Windows the command would be: `where *python`

Comment: what should I be using?

Comment: John how do I check if its set the the $path?

Comment: @JakeStrouse From your shell, run the command "which python": https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKEip.png. If you are running on a windows machine the command should instead be: "where *python". If you get nothing back (e.g. the shell just returns a new prompt), that means that your operating system doesn't have Python listed in the $PATH variable (On windows you will get this error back instead: "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).").

Comment: what is really confusing me is that I just reinstalled pip and I can see it in 'C:\Users\jakes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages'
but I still cannot run the 'pip' command in cmd, nor can I run it in py.exe.

Comment: What happens if you run the `pip` command directly out of the directory you just linked: C:\Users\jakes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages? You should be able to run `dir C:\Users\jakes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages` followed by `pip --version` and get a version number back. If running pip from its installed directory works, then you know its a $PATH issue that prevents you from running pip elsewhere within the filesystem. If you're unable to run pip from within it's installed directory, something is corrupted with your install.

Comment: I ran it in that directory and it didn't recognized'pip'. I have reinstalled pip using https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py but still doesn't recognizedpip.

Comment: @JakeStrouse I figured out once I got onto a Windows machine that the Pip you are likely seeing in that directory is not an executable file. I've added an answer with some instructions on next steps to get you up and running.

Answer (score 0):

*Welcome to stackoverflow!*

> this is an image i took from a website if you would like to use PIP
>
> > [image]

the website: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the directory that you specified in your comment. Pip is not an executable file there, but rather is python source code. What I found that worked and allowed me to run Pip successfully was to import Pip as a module within the system Python environment. Then run Python specifying Pip as a loaded module using the `-m` flag to call pip as an executable with its own arguments (e.g. `C:\Users>python -m pip --version`). The steps to set this up are included below:

**Step 1: Verify that Python is installed and is added to your PATH variable**

From cmd, run the command: `C:\Users> where python`. You should be returned a file path to the executable for Python.

[image: commands to locate system Python]

If instead you receive an error message that says the following: "INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s)." that means that Python is not added to your $PATH variable (See below for details on how to configure your PATH variable.

**Step 2: Add Pip source code as a module within Python**

- Run python from the cmd: `C:\Users> python`
- Run the command `import pip` within the python shell:
- Run the command `exit()` to return to the cmd from the Python shell.

[image: commands to import pip as a module within system Python]

**Step 3: Validate that pip can be used as a module within Python**

- Run the following command to check Pip's version as a validation that Pip and Python are configured correctly: `C:\Users> python -m pip --version`
- Validate that you are returned a version number

[image: running pip command]

**Configuring PATH environment variable (Windows 10)**

- From the start menu search box, type "edit the system environment variables".
- Open the application that is returned (should pop open the control panel).
- Click the button entitled 'Environment Variables'
- If you have a variable defined as 'PATH' already, click the edit button, then click 'new' in the following dialog box. Specify the path to your Python executable ( C:\Users\jakes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages). Click 'Ok' and then 'Apply.'

[image]

- If you don't already have a 'PATH' variable defined, click 'new' and define a name of 'PATH' and add in the file path to the Python executable as the variable's value.
- **Close any active Command Prompts!** After making changes to your PATH variable,you will need to close any active sessions in order to allow the update PATH variable to be propagated within the session.
- Open a new Command Prompt window and run the command: `C:\Users> where python` to verify that the your changes were made correctly, and that they have fully propagated within the system.

Comment: Thank you so much for this response, I do have some slight problems. I still cannot run the command 'pip [file]'. This is what I have done: https://gyazo.com/e2007febd58baa4022d2b4f576fdfcca
This is my pip version and the 'where py'
https://gyazo.com/ed700699528dd4253c6c571ae1009b0d

Comment: In the same way that you're running the `pip --version` command as `C:\Windows\System32>py -m pip --version`, you will need to run the file command as `C:\Windows\System32>py -m pip [filename]`.

Comment: thanks so much for that! I do have one more small question. I used that to install pyinstaller and everything went well, it asked me to add something to the $PATH and I did that. The problem is when I direct to the file I want to compile, and I type 'py -m pyinstaller snake.py' it responds with 'C:\Users\jakes\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe: No module named pyinstaller'

Comment: If you've installed pyinstaller, and it's on your PATH, you should be able to just execute `pyinstaller snake.py` directly. Because pyinstaller is an executable file, rather than a module, you can call it directly. Just make sure you're in the directory that contains snake.py and you should be good.